# LINQ count items created before or the same day past X days

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am stuck at writing LINQ query to count items created before or the same day past X days.

I have the following table `Items`:

```
id   dateline (timestamp)  lastactivity  status   
-----------------------------------------------------
1    1448395260            1448395260    done    
2    1448308860            1448308999    in_progress
3    1448308860            1448395260    done
4    1448222460            1448395260    done
5    1448395260            1448395260    in_progress
```

I am trying to write LINQ query to get the number of created and existing in_progress items per day for past X days. 
Item is counted if it's `dateline <= DAY_END (23:59:59) AND (status != 'done' OR lastactivity >= DAY_START (00:00:00))`.
If item's dateline is less then specific day and it was closed on that day is must be counted.

According to table items above, expected result should be something like this:

```
day           not_done_items_count
-----------------------------------
1448409599    5
1448323199    3
1448236799    1
```

(For the `day` value I took `DAY_END` timestamp.)

My current LINQ query looks like this:

```
var itemsPerDay = (from item in items
                   from i in Enumerable.Range(0, totalDays)
                   let dayStart = start.AddDays(i).ToUnixTimestamp()
                   let nextDay = start.AddDays(i).NextDay().ToUnixTimestamp()
                   where (item.dateline < nextDay
                       && (!item.status.Equals("done") || t.lastactivity >= dayStart)
                   select new { day = nextDay - 1 }
                  ).ToList();

var results = itemsPerDay.DistinctBy(t => t.day).Select(
    t => new OpenedItemsPerDay
    {
        day = t.day,
        count = itemsPerDay.Count(v => v.day == t.day)
    }).AsQueryable();
```

The code above executes too slowly and I am not sure if it is a correct way to do what I am trying to.

I also tried to play around with grouping but stucked: if the item was created earlier then DAY_X and it's status changed to done for example 2 days after I can only relate it to one group (day), I can't count it twice or more.

Comment: Have you tried to run the query using raw SQL

Comment: @AlexKrupka Yes, I have. I have written some simple query builder which generates me SQL query like this: `SELECT * FROM items WHERE dateline <= DAY_END AND (status != 'done' OR lastactivity >= DAY+1_START) OR dateline <= DAY+1_END AND (status != 'done' OR lastactivity >= DAY+1_START)`, and repeats that 30 times. And then I manually count items. I think there might be a better way to do this.

Comment: Since this requires sequential processing (a kind of running total) it's much easier and faster to get the raw data from the database and process them in memory in a classic `foreach`. Currently you have a cross join with a local sequence. EF is not particularly efficient in translating local sequences into SQL and the query optimizer will have a hard time finding a good plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use groupby?  ( not infront of vs so pardon the syntax )

```
var d1 = datetime.now.adddays(-5).ToUnixTimestamp()
var d2= DateTime.Now.ToUnixTimestamp();

var grouppeditems = (for item in items
where item.lastactivity <= d2 && item.dateline >= d1 && (!item.status.Equals("done")
select item).GroupBy(gb=>gb.lastactivity)

foreach (var item in grouppeditems )
 Console.WriteLine ( item.Title + " " +  item.Count);
```

//might wanna group by something like this to group the same day 
(d2-gb.lastactivity)/86400

Comment: lastactivity field is timestamp, it will group by same timestamps, i need to group by days.

Comment: might wanna group by something like this to group the same day (d2-gb.lastactivity)/86400